# Search a file for a string and replace everything after a character in that line

Tags: php, file-writing

I am looking to use PHP to open a file (see example below), search it line by line for a string `$colour` and replace everything after the `=` with `$value`.

file.txt before:

```
red=0
green=23
blue=999
yellow=44
```

If my `$value` is `"1"` and my colour is `"blue"`, my file should change to:

```
red=0
green=23
blue=1
yellow=44
```

My code so far is:

```
function write($colour, $value) {
    $file = 'path';
    $file_contents = file_get_contents($file);
    $file_contents = str_replace($colour, $value, $file_contents);
    file_put_contents($file, $file_contents);
}
```

However this only gets as far as replacing the `$colour` with the `$value` (not everything after the "=") see below my output:

```
red=0
green=23
1=999
yellow=44
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are just replacing the text of the colour with the value in

```
$file_contents = str_replace($colour, $value, $file_contents);
```

this doesn't replace the full line though.

Using `preg_replace()`, you can replace something starting with the colour followed by and `=` till the end of line with...

```
$file_contents = preg_replace("/{$colour}=.*/", "{$colour}={$value}", $file_contents);
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because your code only replaces color with value specified. To do this you would have to load file line by line, explode by = to have color and value separetely, adjust and store again. Or use regexes.

I would like to propose different approach. Instead on operating on file loaded as string, load file as array. There is a function for this: parse_ini_file.

```
<?php

// load the file to array with elements key => value
$data = parse_ini_file('conf.txt');

var_dump($data);

// change the data in array however you want - here i add 1 to red everytime this script is called, but it can be whatever: $data['red'] = 2; or similar
$data['red']++;

// now just build the contents of the file again and save it
$contents = '';
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
  $contents .= $key.'='.$value.PHP_EOL;
}

file_put_contents('conf.txt', $contents);
```

Result:

```
// this is how the file looks like at start
cat conf.txt 
red=0
green=23
blue=1
yellow=44

// this is how $data looks
array(4) {
  ["red"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["green"]=>
  string(2) "23"
  ["blue"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["yellow"]=>
  string(2) "44"
}

// and the file after the execution
cat conf.txt 
red=1
green=23
blue=1
yellow=44
```

Change `$data['red']++;` to `$data[$color] = $value;` put it into a function and thats it.